# Bootstrap table row hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover, row, css-tables

How do I make the background change of a table row in `Bootstrap 3` on hover. The table class I am using right now is `table table-striped`. I tried to add a extra class to the `<tr>` tags within the table and made the css like this `.table-row:hover{background:black;}`. Now only the non-striped rows are working. Isn't there a class in bootstrap that will allow me to easily implement this? Or should I use `JQuery` to fix this? I really cannot figure this one out by myself.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You need to add the `table-hover` class to the `<table/>` element. Like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>Col 1</td>
           <td>Col 2 </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Source: [Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables)

Comment: Note, you have to put table-striped before table-hover or striped rows won't highlight on hover

Comment: @GeorgiiOleinikov it's actually the opposite with bootstrap 3, but thanx for the tip!

Comment: that works for tr inside tbody. for generated tables like asp.net gridview, it also applies to the th.